# What is the right place for reusable render functions in WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, reusability

Let's say I have a reusable peace of HTML used on different pages in my theme.
In order to not duplicate myself I want to put this peace of HTML into some place and reuse it later. And because it has some parameters (needed for rendering) - it should be a function.

It seems to me that I cannot use `get_template_part` function because I want to pass some parameters into the render function.

`functions.php` feels more like a place for low level theme functionality.

What is the right place for render functions in WordPress?

**UPD** I've just found that in `_s` theme that I am using as a base code for my theme they have `inc/template-tags.php`. It feels like a good place. Is it the right way?

Comment: you can pass parameter to `get_template_part` .

Comment: Only `get_template_part( $slug, $name );`. I cannot pass let's say `$customer_name` in there...

Comment: Check my answer now, use set_query_var and get_query_var to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

check codex [set_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_query_var) and [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

In main template

```
set_query_var('customer_name', $customer_name);
get_template_part( $slug, $name );
```

template part retrieve it as

```
$customer_name= get_query_var( 'customer_name', 1 );  
echo $customer_name;
```

Comment: Well it will work but it doesn't look like a nice approach.

Comment: OMG I see that it is recommended by wordpress ... hm https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Passing_Variables_to_Template

Comment: Still it feels like a bad architecture. Because then `$wp_query` becomes a mess. In my case I am rendering a list of items. So what I want to place into function is HTML for a single item. And this render function is called in a loop. So it doesn't look nice to update `$wp_query` on each iteration...

Comment: @chestozo  why your $wp_query will become a mess ?Can you explain me your problem in a better way ?

Comment: I have a list of items that I am rendering in a loop. I need a function that I can call on each iteration (for each list item). If I use `set_query_var` and `get_query_var` values will be stored in `$wp_query` and I don't think this is the best place for such information. In docs it says:  "`$wp_query` object information defining the current request". So it is ok to store information about the request but it is not good to use as a global variables storage unrelated directly to request. IMHO

Comment: @chestozo I think that is why you reset your $wp_query using wp_reset_query() after the loop .Read this http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012 It may give you better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in `_s` theme they suggest:

> Custom template tags in `inc/template-tags.php` that keep your templates clean and neat and prevent code duplication.

Seems like a good place was found :)

Comment: It's not exactly clear how this answers the question; can you add some detail? I've edited out the question part of your answer, as it detracts from the "answer" feel of it. For future reference, we also have a http://wordpress.stackexchange.com site, which you can also use to get advise/ help on Wordpress related questions.

Comment: I have described my case in detail in this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999247/what-is-the-right-place-for-reusable-render-functions-in-wordpress-theme#comment55771844_33999445